Why did scientists believe in an eternal universe before Lemaitre, even if the Kelvin paradox was already known since the 19th century?
Why did scientists believe in a static and eternal universe in Einstein times, before Lamaitre showed that the Einstein equations are compatible with a universe which started from a primeval atom, even if the Kelvin paradox was already known since the 19th century?

They couldn't believe it. That's it. People didn't accept SR immediately, did they? But it took less time cause people were beginning to understand science. I know I can't write it as an answer though.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Your question would be a good fit for HSM SE.

Identifying things which we believe without evidence, and then coming up with evidence which tests those beliefs, is fundamental to the practice of science.

You have to appreciate the dominance of Newtonian physics until the 20th century.  The mechanics of Newton relied on the concepts of absolute space and time.  The efficacy of Newtonian physics and the disconnection of gravity from time and space in that model made the eternality of the universe a settled issue until modern observations overturned that paradigm. So it wasn't fully a question of preference, but a position rooted in the science known at the time.
